# WooCommerce One Page Checkout: Show credit card payment fields even when cart is empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, credit-card, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to bend WooCommerce to my will --the end goal is to have a one-page donation form, where all the fields, variations, billing information and credit card information is collected all on one page.

I have the WooCommerce One Page checkout to help me do this --but, I need the credit card fields to always show.  Right now, they are hidden, and only show up when there's something in the cart.

FYI, I'm using Sage Payments USA to handle payments (if that makes any difference).

Can you please help me display the credit cards fields even when the cart is empty?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

- Roselle

P.S. Here's the page in question: https://dev.sanma.org/sponsor-a-project/

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's normal behaviour that prevents checking out with an empty cart.
Are you using any specific plugins, like e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-quick-donation/ ?

Comment: I am married to WooCommerce since I have to use a certain payment gateway.  If not for this, I'd just use Gravity Forms with PayPal Payments Pro and be done with it.  

But, since I have to use WooCommerce to make a donation form, I just used the Gravity Forms WooCommerce add-on to make the form, and the One Page Checkout WooCommerce extension to condense the process of "Product => Cart => Checkout"   to just one page.

The problem is that I need the credit card boxes to always show up, regardless of whether there's something in the cart.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, because this would mean a possibility to check out with empty cart. And checking out with empty cart is almost like signing up with empty login/password :) You may want to review your process though - think about UX that doesn't require CC fields to be shown immediately.